# Как и от куда передать значение координат в GoogleMap?

Tags: android, массивы, android-fragment, координаты

Из фрагмента(список городов),по нажатию на пункт из списка в нем(фрагмента) открывается Activity  с фрагментом гуглМапс. не могу разобраться как передать координаты в фрагмент googleMaps. В документации написано как задать координаты с маркером,но как их передавать из массива не сказано.

**Вот код массива для фрагмента**

```
class MosOblClass {

private String nameOblMos;
private int imageId;
private String coordinator;

static final MosOblClass[] mosObl = {
        new MosOblClass("Рузское водохранилище", "geo:36.051622,122.310075", R.drawable.flat_19),
        new MosOblClass("Можайское водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075",R.drawable.flat_12),
        new MosOblClass("Озеро Морозово", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_13),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_10),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_11),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_12),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_13),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_14),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_15),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_17),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_18),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_19),

};


  private MosOblClass(String nameOblMos,String coordinator, int imageId) {
    this.nameOblMos = nameOblMos;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.coordinator = coordinator;


}

public String getName() {
    return nameOblMos;
}

public String getCoordinator() {
    return coordinator;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {return imageId;
}
}
```

**Класс фрагмента GoogleMaps**

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements      OnMapReadyCallback {

SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
GoogleMap map;
final String TAG = "myLogs";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);

    setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    LatLng mesto = new LatLng(0,0);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mesto).title("name"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mesto));
}

}
```

**Вот сам фрагмент от куда необходимо передать данные**

```
public class MosOblFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerAdapter.Listener mListener;




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final RecyclerView moscowRecycler = (RecyclerView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_oblasty,
            container, false);
    final String[] oblastyName = new String[mosObl.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < oblastyName.length; i++){
        oblastyName[i] = mosObl[i].getName();
    }

    final String[] oblastyGeo = new String[mosObl.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < oblastyGeo.length; i++){
        oblastyGeo[i] = mosObl[i].getCoordinator();
    }

    int[]moscowImage = new int[mosObl.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < moscowImage.length; i++) {
        moscowImage[i] = mosObl[i].getImageResourceId();
    }

    RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(oblastyName,oblastyGeo, moscowImage);
    moscowRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    moscowRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter.setListener(new RecyclerAdapter.Listener() {
        public void onClick(int position) {

            /*
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GameActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", mosObl[position].getName());
            intent.putExtra("new", mosObl[position].getCoordinator());
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");


            //intent.putExtra(OblastyMoscowActivity.EXTRA_OBLASTYMO, position);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            */
        }
    });
    return  moscowRecycler;
}
}
```

Comment: Проставленные вами ранее метки практически лишали вопрос и шанса на то что его заметят. Тем паче что `android-studio` тег к вопросу совсем не относится. Постарайтесь отформатировать нормально код (выделив и нажав в редакторе на фигурные скобки). И попробуйте локализовать проблему. Кажется ваш вопрос вообще не про карты, а про передачу кастомных классов-объектов из активити во фрагмент

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. поробую более конкретно оформить вопрос

Comment: Для передачи данных между Активностью и фрагментом нужно использовать дополнения для фрагментов, и получать их из Bundle savedInstanceState